# Disable delete cascade on one to many in same table Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is my table, so an user can have a manager which is also an user :

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int? AttachedManagerId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser AttachedManager { get; set; }
}
```

And this is to try to disable the delete of attached users when a manager is deleted :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(s => s.AttachedManager)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.AttachedManagerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}
```

When i add a migration, it generate this :

```
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_AspNetUsers_AspNetUsers_AttachedManagerId",
    table: "AspNetUsers",
    column: "AttachedManagerId",
    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.SetNull) ;
```

so i have this error :

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class
>   'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_AspNetUsers_AspNetUsers_AttachedManagerId' on table 'AspNetUsers'
>   may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

Comment: I guess here `public class User` you mean `ApplicationUser`? Anyway, use `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)`, all other options imply some sort of cascade operation, hence "multiple cascade paths".